# Remover valor de um array

Tags: python, array

O meu array é montado da seguinte forma:

```
obstacles = [[x, y], [x, y], ...]
```

Estou querendo remover do array uma posição [x, y]

Porém a função `obstacles.remove()` está desligando o servidor quando executada, se eu comenta-la, o resto funciona normalmente.

```
obstacles = []

class...

        if event[0] == 'position':
            oldPosX = self.__getattribute__('positionX')
            oldPosY = self.__getattribute__('positionY')

            obstacles.remove([int(oldPosX), int(oldPosY)])

            self.from_to(int(event[1]), int(event[2]), int(oldPosX), int(oldPosY), int(event[3]), int(event[4]), obstacles) '''função para cacular o path.'''

            if [int(event[3]), int(event[4])] not in obstacles:
                obstacles.append([int(event[3]), int(event[4])]) '''adiciona posição [x, y] no array'''
```

Comment: Você não precisa -  e não deveria - fazer coisas como `self.__getattribute__('positionX')` - apenas `self.positionX` tem o mesmo efeito. Se por acaso, você tiver o nome `"positionX"` numa variável e queira usar a variável, use `getattr(self, <variável>)`)

Answer (score 1):

Quando tiver um erro, sempre veja a mensagem de erro que aparece no terminal. Se aí não descobrir o que está acontecendo, ao fazer uma pergunta, inclua a mensagem de erro junto com o seu código.

Nesse caso, você teria visto que a mensagem é do tipo

> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

ou seja: seu programa parou com um erro por que o elemento que você tentou remover da lista usando `remove` não estava na lista.

A forma mais simples de resolver o erro (embora seu programa pudesse ter outras melhorias) é testar pela presença do elemento antes de tentar remove-lo:

```
oldpos = [int(oldPosX), int(oldPosY)]
if oldpos in obstacles:
    obstacles.remove([int(oldPosX), int(oldPosY)])
```

Isso vai eliminar este erro. Quanto ao motivo dele não estar encontrando o conjunto de coordenadas, podem ser vários: mas sugiro começar vendo no seu código se você os arredondou para inteiros ao coloca-los na lista.

Uma outra dica sobre o código: remover elementos de lista com "remove" pode ser ineficiente - por que o Python tem que percorrer a lista inteira antes de remover o elemento. Se o seu "obstacles" não precisa saber sobre a ordem das coordenadas lá dentro, use um `set` (conjunto) em vez de uma lista - (e use `tuple` e não `list` para os pares de coordenada lá dentro): o tempo de remover um elemento de um `set` é constante.

Dica para postar perguntas: sempre coloque toda a declaração de classes e funções  com o contexto necessário par podermos responer uma pergunta - então:

```
obstcales = []
class Nome(object):
   ...
   def minhafunc(self, arg1, arg2):

       ...
       if event == 'position': 
           ...
```

Fica bem díficil respodner sobre "position" se não sabemos como foi declarada, e o que tem dentro dela. Se o código for pequeno, procure colocar o código todo.  Ao contrário de outras linguagens onde você precisa de muito código, sempre igual, para chegar no "núcleo" onde acontece alguma coisa, em Python o "boiler plate" é mínimo: ajuda muito ver todo o contexto.

E por fim, não custa repertir: sempre, sempre veja a mensagem de erro que o Python joga no terminal quando um programa dá erro. Ele nunca simplesmente "para o servidor". (Exceto em raros casos onde acontece uma falha de segmentação em um módulo de terceiros)